# how to display an option menu when an activity starts

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu, optionmenu

I've activity that i want an option menu to be displayed on. But, i want the option menu to be displayed all the time the activity is displayed. I don't want my users to click (select) the menu button to display it. I want it to be there all the time. How can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

`Activity.openOptionsMenu()`.

From a design standpoint, I have to agree with Mayra. Wrong approach to begin with.

Comment: my activity crash after calling that method... any clues? @EboMike

Comment: @gumuruh The log should tell you why. You may want to open a new question for this.

Comment: I think.... i'll set the targetSDk on the Android to be more lower to ensure it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want options to appear at the bottom of the screen always, don't use the options menu.  Just place buttons at the bottom of your screen.

However, keep in mind that this goes against the "Android way" of doing things, so make sure you understand how Android users are going to expect your application to look and work, and you have a good reason for doing something different.